# How to exclude all subsequences of string from a long string in Java

Tags: java, regex, regular-language

How can I write code in Java using Regex and ReplaceAll method which would exclude all sub sequences from long string:

> :' goes to '
>   :+ goes to +
>   +' goes to '

For example, if i have:

> string U:'0 that after reduction be U'0
>    string U+'0 that after reduction be U'0

If I have a long string, the operation should be repeated until all combinations of those three operations no longer changes the string.

I am not so good with regular expressions, so I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: your example is pretty unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that regular expressions are the correct tool for this. Is there any reason why you can't just do:

```
String myString = "This U:'0 is a U+'0 string."
myString = myString.Replace(":'", "'");
myString = myString.Replace(":+", "+");
myString = myString.Replace("+'", "'");
```

Unless the logic behind the transformations is far more involved than you are actually suggesting, there's no reason why this wouldn't be sufficient.